# how to run java code in pentaho "user define java class"

Tags: java

I need to get file from linux server to windows so i make java code and tested it on eclipse its working fine, now i want to put same code in pentaho, but its not working there. i put jar file as mention in this link.

need to run it in pentaho

```
package sftp;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class sftp {


    public sftp() {
        super();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String SFTPHOST = "XX.XX.XXX.XX";
        int SFTPPORT = 22;
        String SFTPUSER = "username";
        String SFTPPASS = "password";
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/aa/bbb/";

        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
            session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(channelSftp.get("aa.csv"));
            File newFile = new File("D:/file.csv");
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            int readCount;
            while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                System.out.println("Writing: ");
                bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done: ");
    }

}
```

this my java code.

see [Reference](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/using-external-jars-import-in-pentaho-data-integration/).

Comment: What happens when you run that code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any error messages or stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

I have run my own java code successfully  in PDI but I used a java script step. First I copied my jar to /lib and not to /libext which shouldn't make a difference if both folders are added to the classpath.

The Modified JavaScript Job Entry in PDI is based on  Rhino JavaScript Engine which allows you to run Java code. You need to use the full qualified class names - with the package and everything but that's usually not a problem since you probably have a step like new mypackage.myclass().doMyJob()

You can check this guide: http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/06/using-java-in-pentaho-kettle/

I would advise you not to use Java directly from the PDI steps though. A better approach would be to add the Jar to the ETL package (the place where your steps are) and to call it externally with a bash script or a system command.

After making multiple ETLs and using JAVA jars directly inside them I would say this is a maintenance hell. First of all the JAR then is not part of your ETL package but it becomes a part of the PDI (by adding itself to the lib folders). When you are in production environment it makes it harder to install the ETL on multiple machines and adds unnecessary complexity. Lots of issue raise like - not having the latest jar in lib folder , the devOps team forgot to copy the jar during installation, on server X PDI is installed with different user and you don't have the rights to copy into lib folder and stuff like that.

Here is an example with my code in the job XML:

```
<entry>
      <name>JavaScript</name>
      <description />
      <type>EVAL</type>
      <script>

    var filename=parent_job.getVariable("filename","");
    var filenameClean=filename+"_clean";
    var useRelevance="false";   
    com.example.CSVParser(filename,filenameClean,useRelevance);
      </script>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>800</xloc>
      <yloc>1008</yloc>
    </entry>
```

Here the script is the actual script of my javascript step in the KJB file. I am calling the constructor of the CSVParser class and the logic is embedded in the constructor (it is cleansing some CSV files)

Edit after I saw the java code:

In order to run a java code from Pentaho that way you need to make it an instance method and not a static one. The code creates an object instance and calls it's method. And you want to run the static main. The problem here is no the PDI part but you should write a proper java class. With object and methods and Capital letter for class name etc. If you want to run that piece of code just compile it into a jar and create a shell file that runs `java -jar sftp`

Comment: i make jar of code and put it into lib folder now in JS Step what i have to write?

Comment: Write something like var myObject= new mypackage.MyClass(); myObject.myMethod()

Comment: not working , var myObject= new sftp.sftp(); 
myObject.main()

Comment: I added my example. You don't need  a main method (if that's private static main then it will not be part of the class). You create an instance and call instance methods

Comment: Well you cannot call the main method. If you want to run the main method you need to run it as a shell script. You need to call an instanace method. I can keep explaining but that's basic java - not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a method

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException;
```

Directly inside the editor instead your `main()`. Think as if the code you put in the editor of the step is surrounded by a class declaration, so your class is treated as an inner one. See https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/User+Defined+Java+Class.

What I don't know is how to import all you need, but I'd try anyway.